How to activate overaly mesh in a swarm having two subnet?
I want to create a cluster having 2 manager nodes and 2 worker nodes under each manager. Each manager forms a sub-cluster with its worker nodes under a sub-net. For such a complex setup, I am using Oracle VirtualBox. I created the following sub-clusters:
sub-clusters     nodes        interface(s)                   IPv4
------------     --------     --------------------------     -------------
sub-cluster1     manager1     enp0s9 (Host-Only Network)     192.168.50.3
                              enp0s8 (NAT-Network)           10.0.1.3
                 worker1-1    enp0s8 (NAT-Network)           10.0.1.4
                 worker1-2    enp0s8 (NAT-Network)           10.0.1.5

sub-cluster2     manager2     enp0s9 (Host-Only Network)     192.168.100.3
                              enp0s8 (NAT-Network)           20.0.1.3
                 worker2-1    enp0s8 (NAT-Network)           20.0.1.4
                 worker2-2    enp0s8 (NAT-Network)           20.0.1.5

In each node, I allowed ports 2377/tcp, 4789/udp and 7946/tcp & 7946/udp with ufw as follows:
sudo ufw allow 2377/tcp
sudo ufw allow 4789/udp
sudo ufw allow 7946/tcp
sudo ufw allow 7946/udp

I initiated the main cluster at manager1 as follows:
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.50.3

and later checked the joining token for a manager:
docker swarm join-token manager

After that, I included manager2 to manager1 as follows:
docker swarm join --token <MANAGER-JOINING-TOKEN-FROM-MANAGER1> 192.168.50.3:2377

Later, I checked the joining token for a worker (at each manager node):
docker swarm join-token worker

and then added the associated workers in the sub-clusters (with associated NAT-Network IPs instead of Host-Only Network IPs) as follows:
# sub-cluster1
docker swarm join --token <WORKER-JOINING-TOKEN-FROM-MANAGER1> 10.0.1.3:2377

# sub-cluster2
docker swarm join --token <WORKER-JOINING-TOKEN-FROM-MANAGER2> 20.0.1.3:2377

The docker node ls command shows that the nodes joined successfully. In the whole cluster, managers can ping each other with their Host-Only Adapter (192.168.x.y). A manager (x.0.1.3) can ping workers in the same sub-net (x.0.1.y) and vice-versa but can not ping from different sub-net. However, I created an overlay network as follows:
docker network create --driver overlay --attachable --subnet 30.0.1.0/24 my-overlay-mesh

The above command created the my-overlay-mesh at both manager nodes (but not in workers). When I deployed the following service it made the my-overlay-mesh at the workers node:
docker service create \
--name nginx-rMesh \
--network my-overlay-mesh \
--constraint node.role==worker \
--replicas 4 --replicas-max-per-node 2 \
--publish target=80,published=80 \
nginx

I was expecting that I could access nginx the service with the manager IPs i.e., curl http://192.168.50.3 or curl http://192.168.100.3. But it didn't work.
What did I miss something here to work with overlay mesh i.e., routing mesh?
EDIT:
When the swarm is initiated in 10.0.1.x/24 subnet with 10.0.1.3 (NAT-Network IP) instead of 192.168.50.3 (Host-Only Network IP), the routing mesh works as expected (e.g., a service is accessible via a manager even though the service is deployed into a worker). Then I applied the port forwarding approach and tried to include a master node & 2 workers from 2nd subnet but I failed to do that.
What would be the best way? Looking for your valuable suggestion. Thanks!

Caution: 2 manager nodes is a fault-intolerant environment. If either manager fails, you lose quorum and the ability to mange the cluster. You need at least 3 managers to continue operating with a single manager down.

@BMitch, I understand the matter. What should I do where the workers are in the subnet?

If you want fault tolerance, add a 3rd manager in a 3rd AZ. If you don't need fault tolerance, then only deploy a single manager.

In docker swarm, all the workers will try to talk to all the managers.

@ChrisBecke, I updated the question. Any suggestion?
